# How to get contact name and mobile number through Facebook messenger API

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger

Now a days Facebook messenger allows 3rd party apps to integrate with it.
My requirement is suppose I am chatting with one of my friend on Facebook messenger. I wanted to get contact name and mobile number of friend whom I am chatting in my sample android app through Facebook messenger API.

I searched but I didn't get the API which matches my requirement.
Does android Facebook SDK / Facebook messenger SDK provide such kind of API?

At least can we get contact name with whom we are chatting in 3rd party app?

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the docs, there's **no API that do this**.

Moreover you cannot get the user phone numbers, Facebook removed that option several years ago.